# Calculate Average of DateInterval

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I'm looking for a way to calculate the average total duration (in `DateInterval` form) of an event. I have the durations in `DateInterval` objects, but I need to sum those up and calculate their average. Solutions I've seen so far have me adding up the different amounts by converting them to seconds, but I need to present the final form in a `DateTime` form.

How can I present the average duration as a `DateTime` value?

EDIT:

Setting the duration as follows (where `$busyTime` and `$freeTime` are DateTime objects):

```
$timetable[$siteID]->duration = $timetable[$siteID]->freeTime->diff($timetable[$siteID]->busyTime,true); //compare time, force to absolute (true)
```

Then I'm trying to sum up the durations, like so:

`$totalDuration += $timetable[$siteID]->duration;`

For this one, I get 129 for both the total duration AND the number of items I'm counting, which implies to me that they are all a value of 1. This is fine if so (maybe 1 second each?) but I'd like to be able to handle more than just seconds. I'm not sure if that's what is happening here.

I also tried the following, though I didn't expect it to work:

`$totalDuration += $timetable[$siteID]->duration->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

For the last one, I get 0.

Comment: You don't. The average length of a set of intervals is no longer a date or a time [aka, a *point* in time], it is a number of seconds. [aka, a *length* of time] You need to do the math to format it into what I assume is a number of days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: So convert it into seconds first; do the average; then convert it back.

Comment: *Somewhat* scratch my previous statement, DateInterval *does* have a [`format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) function, but it functions entirely differently than `DateTime::format()` does because it operates on a *length* of time rather than a point.

Comment: Yeah I've found that, I'm just curious on how to do calculations with the duration value itself. Is it in seconds by default, and I can do the calculation with that, and then use format to display it a different way? Time to do some reading of the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simple create `DateTime` object with timestamp = `0`; then `->add()` all your `Dateinterval`'s to that object; fetch `->getTimestamp()` and divide it by number intervals added. You will get average number of seconds; example:

```php
function calculateIntervalAverage() {
    $offset = new DateTime('@0');
    foreach (func_get_args() as $interval) {
        $offset->add($interval);
    }
    return round($offset->getTimestamp() / func_num_args());
}
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/80595)**</kbd>

If you wish to convert seconds to `DateInterval` object, you can just create it with `PTxS` parameter:

```php
$interval = new DateInterval("PT3600S");
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/80596)**</kbd>

But this will not calculate carry-over-points, like you see on demo. If this is a problem, you can still [recalculate carry-over-points](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php#113204); example:

```php
class DateIntervalEnhanced extends DateInterval {

    public function recalculate()
    {
        $from = new DateTime('@0');
        $to = clone $from;
        $to->add($this);
        $diff = $from->diff($to);
        foreach ($diff as $k => $v) $this->$k = $v;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/80602)**</kbd>